# VBA Data Validation as soon as user enter data

Tags: forms, vba, validation, duplicates

Hello I got this code and there is a function to check if the user is about to enter an invoice number that already exist. Actually, this function occurs only when the whole form as been filled and is about to be stored in a table but I would like the validation to be done as soon as the user enter the data.

Here is my actual code:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim L As Long
Dim factureWs As Worksheet
Dim rng As Range
Dim thColor As XlThemeColor

If MsgBox("Confirm?", vbYesNo, "Confirming new invoice") = vbNo Then Exit Sub

Set factureWs = Worksheets("FACTURE") '<--| set the worksheet you want to work with

L = GetLastNonEmptyRow(factureWs, "D", 12) + 1 '<--| get passed worksheet first empty row after last non empty one in column "D" from row 12 (included)

If L > 0 Then If Not CheckDuplicate(Me.TextBox2, factureWs.Range("D12:D" & L - 1)) Then Exit Sub '<--| exit if duplicated non accepted by the user

FillRanges factureWs, L '<--| fill worksheet ranges with userfom controls values

With Me
If .OptionButton1 Then
    FormatCell Range("B" & L), xlThemeColorAccent3
ElseIf .OptionButton2 Then
    FormatCell Range("B" & L), xlThemeColorAccent1
ElseIf .OptionButton3 Then
    FormatCell Range("B" & L), xlThemeColorAccent4
Else
    FormatCell Range("B" & L), xlThemeColorAccent2
End If
End With

End Sub
```

And here is the function

```
Function CheckDuplicate(factureNo As String, rng As Range) As Boolean
    Dim f As Range
    Set f = rng.Find(what:=factureNo, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole)
    If Not f Is Nothing Then
        CheckDuplicate = MsgBox("This invoice number already exist!" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "Continue?", vbExclamation + vbYesNo, "Duplicate alert") = vbYes
    Else
        CheckDuplicate = True
    End If
End Function
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Do you want to find duplicates when the user enters the data in `factureWs.Range("D12:D" & L - 1))` ? in that case you need to call  `Function CheckDuplicate` in the event of `Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)` of your "FACTURE" Sheet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could add the following event handler in your userform module;

```
Private Sub TextBox2_Change()
    Dim L As Long
    Dim factureWs As Worksheet

    Set factureWs = Worksheets("FACTURE")
    L = GetLastNonEmptyRow(factureWs, "D", 12) + 1 '<--| get passed worksheet first empty row after last non empty one in column "D" from row 12 (included)
    If L <= 12 Then Exit Sub '<--| exit if no data in worksheet "FACTURE"

    With Me.TextBox2
        If Not CheckDuplicate(.Text, factureWs.Range("D12:D" & L - 1)) Then .Text = Left(.Text, Len(.Text) - 1)  '<--| erase the last character that triggered the duplication issue
    End With
End Sub
```

I wrote it for `TextBox2` control, just change "TextBox2" to your actual textbox name

as a side note, since there seem to be more than one userform sub that uses `factureWs` you may want to declare it at a userform level (and have it "seen" in any userform sub/function) and set it at userform initializing:

```
Option Explicit

Dim factureWs As Worksheet '<--| declare 'factureWs' at the userform level

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Set factureWs = Worksheets("FACTURE") '<--| set 'factureWs' a the userform initializing
End Sub

...

Private Sub TextBox2_Change()
    Dim L As Long

    L = GetLastNonEmptyRow(factureWs, "D", 12) + 1 '<--| get passed worksheet first empty row after last non empty one in column "D" from row 12 (included)
    If L <= 12 Then Exit Sub '<--| exit if no data in worksheet "FACTURE"

    With Me.TextBox2
        If Not CheckDuplicate(.Text, factureWs.Range("D12:D" & L - 1)) Then .Text = Left(.Text, Len(.Text) - 1)  '<--| erase the last character that triggered the duplication issue
    End With
End Sub
```

...

Answer (score 1):

You should use either the `TextBox2_BeforeUpdate` or `TextBox2_Exit`.

The `Change` event updates after every `KeyPress`.  So for example, if you have an #Invoice 123 and you tried to enter a new #Invoice 1234 the duplicates message will incorrectly appear.

### TextBox2_BeforeUpdate Event

```
Private Sub TextBox2_BeforeUpdate(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean)
    Const msg = "This invoice number already exist!" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "Continue?"
    With Worksheets("FACTURE")
        If Not .Range("D12", .Range("D" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp)).Find(what:=Me.TextBox2, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole) Is Nothing Then
            If Not MsgBox(msg, vbExclamation + vbYesNo, "Duplicate alert") = vbYes Then
                Me.TextBox2 = ""
            End If
        End If
    End With

End Sub
```

### TextBox2_Exit Event

```
Private Sub TextBox2_Exit(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean)

    Const msg = "This invoice number already exist!" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "Continue?"
    With Worksheets("FACTURE")
        If Not .Range("D12", .Range("D" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp)).Find(what:=Me.TextBox2, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole) Is Nothing Then
            If Not MsgBox(msg, vbExclamation + vbYesNo, "Duplicate alert") = vbYes Then
                Cancel = True
            End If
        End If
    End With

End Sub
```